# changing original element changes the copy as well

Tags: python, reference

Hi I tried to copy a list within a list as shown below.

```
top = best[0]
```

then I made a modification on variable 'best' and somehow variable 'top' also changes. I know this because I append some elements to the variable 'best'. How do I make sure the value of the variable 'top' stays the same?

Thank you

Comment: check https://www.python-course.eu/deep_copy.php

Answer (score 0):

You could try `top = best[0].copy()`.